# Android, Eclipse, Google_Play_Services_Lib - trying to import the project and getting errors

Tags: android, eclipse, manifest

I have installed Google Play Services SDK, copied the project to my workspace, took off read only property, and tried to import google_play_services_lib into eclipse and I start off by having an error on the manifest file, I look in and its blank. I open the manifest in an xml editor right from windows explorer and it is populated. I copied what was there into the eclipse manifest file and saved it. the error on the manifest file went away, however, now almost all of the files/folders in the res directory are showing errors. I have found almost nothing online about this issue, any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: How would I get a LogCat? The code doesn't compile. the only error I get is:

```
[2013-12-06 10:00:53 - google-play-services_lib] Project has no target set. Edit the   project properties to set one.
[2013-12-06 10:00:53 - google-play-services_lib] Project has no target set. Edit the project properties to set one.
[2013-12-06 10:00:53 - google-play-services_lib] Parser exception for /google-play-services_lib/AndroidManifest.xml: Premature end of file.
[2013-12-06 10:00:55 - google-play-services_lib] Parser exception for /google-play-services_lib/AndroidManifest.xml: Premature end of file.
```

Tutorial followed: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

EDIT: AnroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.google.android.gms"
android:versionCode="4030530"
android:versionName="4.0.30 (889083-30)" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14"/>
```

Comment: post your log-cat and even code...,if you followed any tutorial post that...

Comment: Did mark it as Library?

Comment: Have you tried restarting eclipse ?

Comment: yes I tried restarting it, actually each time i restart the Manifest gets emptied.

Answer (score 3):

I've just encountered the same problem and figered out a solutions that works at least for me. Rather than copying `google-play-services_lib` directory manually into your workspace, try the following:

1. Go to `File -> Import -> Android -> Existing Android Code Into Workspace`
2. Select `Browse`
3. Select `YOUR_SDK_PATH/android-sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/`
4. Mark `Copy projects into workspace`
5. Click `Finish`

Comment: Most people forget to do the 4th step.
Mark Copy projects into workspace

Answer (score -1):

make sure both the library project of GOOGLE PLAY SERVICE and your project's workspace exists in same drive.... i.e if you worspace is in D: drive, make sure your library project should reside in same